# how to define error status check function in Makefile

Tags: makefile

In my `makefile` I have

run_sh:

```
echo"run script";\
toolk -run -tcl sequence.tcl | tee ./log/catch.log;\
$(call chck "./log/catch.log")
```

I want to catch `error status=0` message from above log file and check, if not "0" exit form make file. so i have written this function and calling it in my target run_sh.

```
define chck
log=$(1)
STAT=`cat $(1) | grep "exit status=0"`
ifneq ($(STAT),"exit status=0")
$(error error in script)
endif
endef
```

Is the correct way to write, because i am getting error.

Comment: The makefile should exit and should not execute any other target once we don't have message "exit status=0" from previous target run in log file.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
run_sh:
    echo"run script"; toolk -run -tcl sequence.tcl | tee ./log/catch.log;
    grep "error status=0" ./log/catch.log || exit
```

**EDIT:**

I don't have access to GNUMake 3.79.1, so we must perform some experiments. Set this rule:

```
run_sh:
    exit
```

and try "make run_sh" (*not* "make" or "make all" or anything else). What is the result? (Don't just say "it doesn't work", show us the output.)

Comment: Also in place of exit mentioned above i tried defining macro $(exit_s)  define exit_s $(error error in script) endef. If i execute make it exits with error without running anything.

Comment: @kunal: `exit` works in a makefile for me-- I tested this before I posted it. What version of Make are you using? (Also, I know why your `exit_s` doesn't work, but first things first.)

Comment: i am using GNU Make version 3.79.1, the exit does not work in the intended way, i mean my default target is all : run_sh run_tcl , if i get error in run_sh exit does not work and run_tcl is still executed which is not intended. Help me out @Beta.